# Wordpress GET /wp-json/wp/v2/posts set search with more words in alternative

Tags: wordpress

Is possible?

For example:
https://xxx.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=yyy OR zzz

I've been searching the net but can't find any solution. Can someone help me?